# capistrano cannot run ssh: no such file or directory

Tags: deployment, ssh, capistrano

I'm new to capistrano and I'm trying to set up a test project, but as you can guess, without much success. When I run `cap deploy:update`, I get following output:

```
$ cap deploy
  * 2014-12-27 21:48:06 executing `deploy'
  * 2014-12-27 21:48:06 executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * 2014-12-27 21:48:06 executing `deploy:update_code'
    executing locally: "git ls-remote git@github.com:hstandaert/test.git production"
    command finished in 1281ms
  * executing "git clone -q -b production git@github.com:hstandaert/test.git/customers/4/b/b/stocksolutions.be/httpd.www/private/releases/20141227204807 && cd /customers/4/b/b/stocksolutions.be/httpd.www/private/releases/20141227204807 && git checkout -q -b deploy 5604624725df4d3c7dd4f88fc77cfd5d9d8ddf26 && (echo 5604624725df4d3c7dd4f88fc77cfd5d9d8ddf26 > /customers/4/b/b/stocksolutions.be/httpd.www/private/releases/20141227204807/REVISION)"
servers: ["ssh.stocksolutions.be"]
stocksolutions.be@ssh.stocksolutions.be's password:
stocksolutions.be@ssh.stocksolutions.be's password:
    [ssh.stocksolutions.be] executing command
 ** [ssh.stocksolutions.be :: out] error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
 ** [ssh.stocksolutions.be :: out] fatal: unable to fork
    command finished in 1611ms
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /customers/4/b/b/stocksolutions.be/httpd.www/private/releases/20141227204807; true"
    servers: ["ssh.stocksolutions.be"]
    [ssh.stocksolutions.be] executing command
    command finished in 957ms
failed: "sh -c 'git clone -q -b production git@github.com:hstandaert/test.git /customers/4/b/b/stocksolutions.be/httpd.www/private/releases/20141227204807 && cd /customers/4/b/b/stocksolutions.be/httpd.www/private/releases/20141227204807 && git checkout -q -b deploy 5604624725df4d3c7dd4f88fc77cfd5d9d8ddf26 && (echo 5604624725df4d3c7dd4f88fc77cfd5d9d8ddf26 > /customers/4/b/b/stocksolutions.be/httpd.www/private/releases/20141227204807/REVISION)'" on ssh.stocksolutions.be
```

And here's the deploy.rb file:

```
begin
    require 'colored'
rescue LoadError
    $stderr.puts <<-INSTALL
You need the both the capistrano-ext and colored gems to deploy this application
Install the gems like this:
    gem install colored
    INSTALL
    exit 1
end

set :application, "stocksolutions"
set :repository,  "git@github.com:hstandaert/test.git"
set :branch, "production"

set :user, 'stocksolutions.be'
set :deploy_to, "/customers/4/b/b/#{user}/httpd.www/private"
set :use_sudo, false

set :scm, :git

default_run_options[:pty] = true

server "ssh.stocksolutions.be", :app, :web

namespace :deploy do
 task :start do ; end
 task :stop do ; end
 task :restart, :roles => :app, :except => { :no_release => true } do
   run "#{try_sudo} touch #{File.join(current_path,'tmp','restart.txt')}"
 end
end
```

Anyone who can spot my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your log seems to suggest that either there is no `ssh` client installed in your deployment server, or the command cannot be found in the server's PATH.

Try if cloning the repo via https instead of ssh will work, by changing the following:

BEFORE

```
set :repository,  "git@github.com:hstandaert/test.git"
```

AFTER

```
set :repository,  "https://github.com/hstandaert/test.git"
```

You'll be asked to provide your login credentials for github to be able to clone the repo.

Comment: My hosting is with one.com. I don't know if that's of any use.

Comment: Can you ssh into your server and try to run the ssh command from there?

Comment: gives me the same errors: 
`error: cannot run ssh: No such file or directory
fatal: unable to fork`

Comment: So then, that's the problem. I updated my answer with a possible workaround. See if it works.